# Windows Server 2019 - renaming files with some naming convention

Tags: powershell, filesystems, rename, window-server-2019

We received a ton of files from our sponsor and the files are all formatted like this

```
[ABCD] Title - Id - Description [RS][x264][CHKSUM].txt
```

I could manually rename one at a time but there are more than 500 files that are sent on a weekly basis.

RS - Reviewer Signature (usually the same person)
CHKSUM - for the file or something.

What I need is the following

```
Title - Id - Description.txt
```

I need to have the [ABCD] and anything after [RS] removed but before the .txt

I am open to suggestions (powershell, or 3rd party app)

Comment: split on the `][` chars and take the part that you want from that list.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of renaming the files with PowerShell

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\SponsorFiles" -Filter *.txt
foreach ($file in $files) {
    #remove square brackets and spaces
    $newName = $file.name -replace ' *(\[.+?\]) *'
    #Remove WhatIf if output is as expected
    Rename-Item -LiteralPath $file.FullName -NewName $newName -WhatIf
}
```